# Python Flowers with Turtle(s) Graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm working with turtle graphics in my programming class in high school and the project is to make a flower following some guidelines and functions the teacher has demonstrated. I completed that in an hour, now I'm trying to draw multiple flowers at one time using more turtle, But I can't get the turtles to use the newly defined functions and the teacher doesn't have time to meet with me one on one to discuss how I could do it

so after about a week of searching (for something I don't know how to ask properly much less look for) I'm going to my favourite question site. so if someone can help me or at least point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
   import turtle

tod = turtle.Turtle
tina = turtle.Turtle
tony = turtle.Turtle
trixie = turtle.Turtle
tron = turtle.Turtle


def petal():
    for i in range(90):
        self.start = self.pos()
        self.fd(1)
        self.rt(1)
    self.rt(90)
    for i in range(90):
        self.fd(1)
        self.rt(1)

def stem(self):
    self.pencolor('green')
    self.fd(220)

def flowerhead(self):
    for i in range(9):
      begin_fill()
      petal()
      self.lt(230)
      end_fill()

def stempetal(self):
    self.seth(90)
    self.rt(15)
    fillcolor('green')
    begin_fill()
    petal()
    end_fill()

def flower1(self):
    flowerhead()
    stem()
    stempetal()

def flower2(self):
    flowerhead()
    self.stem()


tod.flower()
```

running that gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\first.last\Desktop\programming\trig class\testflowerclass.py", line 49, in <module>
    tod.flower()
AttributeError: type object 'Turtle' has no attribute 'flower'
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is no `tod.flower()` call in your snippet. Maybe you posted the wrong code?

Comment: that's the code i typed to i have define something as tod flower for it to work (not too experienced with python) and if so will i have to define everything again for every turtle????

Comment: I do not understand what you're saying. I get no errors when I run your code, although it doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: The functions you have defined appear to be cut from a class as they are referencing self. If you wrote them as to extend `turtle.Turtle` then you should probably subclass `turtle.Turtle`

Comment: Also, your turtles aren't instances of your class. You probably need `tod = turtle.Turtle()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of (python) programming you are working with, but without any familiarity appears to be classes, instances and inheritance. There's what appears to be an entry-level tutorial on classes here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes

It seems quite mean to having an assignment on this topic without having had it introduced first.

You probably need to be structuring your code along the lines of:

```
from turtle import Turtle

class MyTurtle(Turtle):
    def my_method(self):
        self.method_defined_in_turtle()
        self.other_method_defined_in_turtle()

todd = MyTurtle()
todd.my_method()
```

Comment: thank you, I'll start looking at that document when I get time

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH